# Spring security 3.2.3 hibernate configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to configure Spring Security with `hibernate` but i am getting this error.

```
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 11, 2014 5:12:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:988)
    at com.mytravly.travlyweb.dao.AbstractHibernateDAO.getCurrentSession(AbstractHibernateDAO.java:52)
    at com.mytravly.travlyweb.dao.AbstractHibernateDAO.findAll(AbstractHibernateDAO.java:30)
    at com.mytravly.travlyweb.service.UserService.getAll(UserService.java:35)
    at com.mytravly.travlyweb.controller.MainController.defaultPage(MainController.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

web.xml
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

```
    <display-name>TravlyWeb</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-database.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">



    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/travlywebdb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
        <value>com.mytravly.travlyweb</value>
      </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean> 

<!--    
   <bean id="userDao" class="com.mytravly.travlyweb.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.mytravly.travlyweb.service.MyUserDetailsService">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />
    </bean> -->
  <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>



</beans>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mytravly.travlyweb" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>
<!-- 
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager> -->

      <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username,password from user where username = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select username,authority from authorities where username = ?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager> 

</beans:beans>
```

controller

```
package com.mytravly.travlyweb.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.mytravly.travlyweb.bean.User;
import com.mytravly.travlyweb.service.UserService;

@Controller
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView defaultPage() {

        List<User> list = service.getAll();

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security + Hibernate Example");
        model.addObject("message", list.get(0).getUsername());

        model.setViewName("hello");
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security + Hibernate Example");
        model.addObject("message", "This page is for ROLE_ADMIN only!");
        model.setViewName("admin");

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout, HttpServletRequest request) {



        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", getErrorMessage(request, "SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"));
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        model.setViewName("login");

        return model;

    }

    // customize the error message
    private String getErrorMessage(HttpServletRequest request, String key) {

        Exception exception = (Exception) request.getSession().getAttribute(key);

        String error = "";
        if (exception instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
            error = "Invalid username and password!";
        } else if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
            error = exception.getMessage();
        } else {
            error = "Invalid username and password!";
        }

        return error;
    }

    // for 403 access denied page
    @RequestMapping(value = "/403", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView accesssDenied() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        // check if user is login
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
            System.out.println(userDetail);

            model.addObject("username", userDetail.getUsername());

        }

        model.setViewName("403");
        return model;

    }





    /*@Autowired
    UserService userService;


    @Autowired
    TestBl bl;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model) {


        return "signin";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signup(Model model) {


        return "signup";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dashboard(Model model) {


        return "blank";
    }*/


}
```

Service

```
package com.mytravly.travlyweb.service;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;



import com.mytravly.travlyweb.bean.User;
import com.mytravly.travlyweb.dao.AbstractHibernateDAO;
import com.mytravly.travlyweb.dao.IGenericDAO;

@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public class UserService {

    public UserService() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    AbstractHibernateDAO<User> dao;

    @Autowired
    public void setDao(final AbstractHibernateDAO<User> userDao) {
        dao = userDao;
        dao.setClazz(User.class);
    }

    public List<User> getAll()
    {
        return dao.findAll();


    }


}
```

AbstractHibernateDAO
    package com.mytravly.travlyweb.dao;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public abstract class AbstractHibernateDAO<T extends Serializable> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setClazz(final Class<T> clazzToSet) {
        clazz = clazzToSet;
    }

    public T getById(final Long id) {
        return (T) getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from " + clazz.getName())
                .list();
    }

    public void save(final T entity) {
        getCurrentSession().persist(entity);
    }

    public void update(final T entity) {
        getCurrentSession().merge(entity);
    }

    public void delete(final T entity) {
        getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }

    public void deleteById(final Long entityId) {
        final T entity = getById(entityId);
        delete(entity);
    }

    protected Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is letting you know that there is no open transaction when you are calling you DAO method and hitting the database. That means that the transaction management of the UserService is wrong.

I would try to change the transaction management of the UserService to create a transaction if there isn't already an existing:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = **Propagation.REQUIRED**)
public class UserService {
```

If this works, the problem could be with the constructing of the spring xmls.

Comment: After changing the Transactional to propagation.required the error is still the same  "No Session found for current thread"